# Different REST representations of the same resource

Tags: json, rest

I have a following situation when designing Rest.

For example I have a list of daily prices

```
[
{"id": 50,
"date": "2018-01-05"},
{"id": 60,
"date": "2018-01-06"},
{"id": 70,
"date": "2018-01-10"}
]
```

First I want to get all the prices in certain period, for example in January with GET /prices/?startDate=2018-01-01&endDate=2018-01-31 and it would return the results as seen above.

Secondly I want to get prices for the the same period but with price=0 where no price exists, such as

```
[
{"price": 50,
"date": "2018-01-05"},
{"price": 60,
"date": "2018-01-06"},
{"price": 0,
"date": "2018-01-07"},
{"price": 0,
"date": "2018-01-08"},
{"price": 0,
"date": "2018-01-09"},
{"price": 70,
"date": "2018-01-10"},
{"price": 0,
"date": "2018-01-11"}
]
```

Could I go with a new endpoint for this such as /prices/in-range/?startDate=2018-01-01&endDate=2018-01-31.

Would that be misleading? Should REST return data that is non-existing such as price=0, or should it be left to client to maniuplate original data?

Is there a naming convention in REST for "derived" data from one resource to another? I am not choosing what data to display, I am basically creating new data here.

Comment: *Would that be misleading?* - yes, considering you already have an endpoint that returns data that this new endpoint is supposed to return, judging by the name

Comment: this needs to be defined between the two integrating systems (client - server). if the design/documentation is to return price 0 then it should be handled as is. 
personally I advocate to have all data processes on the server side ( have the clients as light as possible).

Comment: *Should REST return data that is non-existing such as price=0* - heavily depends on the logic of your application. Usually not, but if you need it.. why not. *should it be left to client to maniuplate original data?* - no, never

Comment: @TimCastelijns is /prices vs  /prices/in-range really that misleading?

Comment: @TimCastelijns my concern is if you have one price in 365 days, you would have to return 364 empty prices and 1 price vs only 1 price. That is why i have a doubt should I go with A, B or maybe A and B (but dont want to confuse the client)

Comment: it is misleading if /prices returns the regular prices and /prices/in-range returns prices, and also the non existing prices

Comment: why do you even need the non existing data?

Comment: I don't see how `in-range` signals that unset prices will be returned as `0`, to me it just suggests the ability to filter over a range of dates, which your original endpoint seems to already have. If you want to be the most accomodating possible to the client, I'd set an additional optional boolean parameter on the original endpoint defaulting to false which, when set to true, make unset prices appear as `0` (or `undefined`) ; something like `returnAbsentPrices`

Comment: @Aaron such as ?startDate=2018-01-01&endDate=2018-01-31&show_empty_prices=true it makes sence - it is basically just a filter

Comment: @TimCastelijns to prevent question such as what happend with price on 2018-01-08 or where are other prices or are you sure there is no price for 2018-01-15 ? and to make their job easer to display range of data without any holes in data

Comment: such questions are not to be answered by spewing out additional data

Comment: @TimCastelijns I agree. but it is not really additional data, it is relevant -
 basic data, just not defined on server side

Comment: if the main purpose is to prevent such questions, it is for sure not relevant. If their main purpose is to make it possible to display the data on the client, it is relevant

Comment: @TimCastelijns I see it more as a serialization of a null parameter. it is not there, but it has some meaning

Comment: look at it from the other side: if it has meaning, why is it not there? Perhaps it should be there (on the server)

Comment: @TimCastelijns i agree, again we go back to nullable values